How to arrive at a theorem of Gauss on automorphisms of the ternary quadratic form $x^2+y^2-z^2$?
According to p.311 of volume 2 of Gauss's collected works, the following theorem on ternary quadratic forms was found posthumously in Gauss's papers.

All transformations of the ternary form $$\begin{pmatrix} 1,& 1,& -1 \\ 0,& 0,&0\end{pmatrix}$$
into itself can be represented by means of the formula $$\begin{pmatrix} \alpha\delta+\beta\gamma&\alpha\beta-\gamma\delta&\alpha\beta+\gamma\delta\\\alpha\gamma-\beta\delta&\frac{1}{2}(\alpha^2+\delta^2-\beta^2-\gamma^2)&\frac{1}{2}(\alpha^2+\gamma^2-\beta^2-\delta^2) \\ \alpha\gamma+\beta\delta & \frac{1}{2}(\alpha^2+\beta^2-\gamma^2-\delta^2)&\frac{1}{2}(\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2+\delta^2) \end{pmatrix}$$ where $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ are integers such that $\alpha\delta-\beta\gamma = 1$.

In "all transformations of the ternary form $x^2+y^2-z^2$ into itself" Gauss means (in modern mathematical terms) all automorphisms of this ternary quadratic form - all integral substitutions $$x'=a_{11}x+a_{12}y+a_{13}z$$
$$y'=a_{21}x+a_{22}y+a_{23}z$$
$$z'=a_{31}x+a_{32}y+a_{33}z$$
such that $x'^2+y'^2-z'^2 = x^2+y^2-z^2$.
According to this page: "the automorphism group of a conic, and indeed the conics themselves, have a special relationship with quaternion algebras.". After that, this page focuses (for the sake of exposition) on conics defined by the Legendre equation $ax^2+by^2+cz^2=0$, of which Gauss's ternary quadratic form is a special case ($a=1,b=1,c=-1$).
The fact that Gauss uses the four integer parameters $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ to express all automorphisms together with the remarks made in the web page just mentioned caught my interest. Perhaps this theorem of Gauss is intimately tied with his understanding of quaternions, and this is a further evidence of his anticipation of extended algebraic systems and their applications (here there is a particular application to number theory). Just to make it clear - unfortunately I am not able to read comprehensively into professional mathematical papers and extract the useful facts/information that will enable me to derive Gauss's theorem.
My question therefore aims to get help in a reconstruction of a proof of Gauss's statement. Useful comments/advices on the guiding principles behind such theorems will be appreciated.

It's in Magnus, Noneuclidean Tesselations and their groups, pages 124, 125. In turn, Fricke and Klein (1897)  which has been translated.

Note that the cleanest example is the form $y^2 - zx$
with   $$\begin{pmatrix} a^2&2ab&b^2\ ac&ad+bc&bd \ c^2 &  2cd&d^2 \end{pmatrix}$$
